# General Solution to a Specific Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**The Original Problem:**

An urn contains 7 white balls and 3 red balls. Balls will be drawn one-by-one at random without replacement until a white ball is drawn. One possible outcome for this experiment is *W* (a white ball is selected on the first draw). Another possible outcome is *RW* (a red on the first draw and a white on the second draw).

a) List all of the possible outcomes. (Hint: There are 4 possible outcomes.)

b) Let $X = \text{number of draws until white ball is obtained}$. Find the probability mass function of $X$ and cumulative distribution function.

c) Find $E(X)$ and $SD(X)$

---

**Updated Problem**

After finding the solution to the original problem, we are tasked to solve the problem again using general terms (unknown amount of each color ball). That is:

$$ \begin{align}
m &= \text{ # of white balls}\\
n &= \text{ # of red balls}\\
R &= \text{red ball}\\
W &= \text{white ball}\\
n &\le m\\
\end{align}$$

I am unsure how to start the CMF, the expected value, and the standard deviation. Any help on where to begin would be much appreciated.

---

**Solution So Far**

a) $W, RW, RRW, ..., nRW$

b) $P(X = x) = \frac{m}{(n - (x - 1)) + m}$

---

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: is this a homework problem?

Comment: Yes. I am not asking for the answer directly, however. I would just like a place to start. Or to know if i am starting the problem correctly.

Comment: OK, can you share your ideas as to how you derived $P(X=x)$? It is not correct as written.

Comment: (1) pmf is quite easy, (2) cdf can be derived from pmf: for 1 ball drawn, the pmf value = cdf value, for two balls drawn, the cdf value = first pmf value + second pmf value, for three balls drawn the cdf value = first pmf value + second pmf value + third pmf value, ... . (3) Expected value is simply $\sum_1^n {n  P(X=n)}$, (4) Standard diviation = $\sqrt{E[X^2] - (E[X])^2}$. $E[x]$ you already have, that is the mean. $E[X^2]$ you calculate as $\sum_1^n {n^2  P(X=n)}$

Comment: You mean the equation or the actual notation $P (X=x) $?

Comment: I think he wants to know why you think that $P(X = x) = \frac{m}{(n-(x-1))+m}$

Comment: The question says to draw until a W is drawn. So as the draws (X) increases, the number of red should decrease with each draw. That was my logic behind it. I may be completely incorrect.

Comment: Could it be that for the easy problem the cdf is $F(1) = \frac{7}{10}$, $F(2) = \frac{7}{9}$, $F(3) = \frac{8}{9}$, $F(3) = \frac{9}{9}$? And that the pmf is given by $f(1) = F(1)$, $f(2) = F(2) - F(1)$, $f(3) = F(3) - F(2)$ and $f(4) = F(4) - F(3)$? Or am I totally wrong? ps: my statement pmf is quite easy is untrue :p

Comment: I believe I might have my PMF equation mixed up with the CDF equation. The problem is I am quite unsure myself.

Comment: You know anything about CDFs? It is just $\leq$ your probability. So what you gave seems to me a random variable which leans to be described more easily by it's CDF then by a PMF. Also we know that the derivative (in continuous case) or difference (in discrete case such as here) of the CDF is the PMF. That's why I wrote those differences. (just noticed a typo, I mean $F(4) = \frac{9}{9}$)

Comment: Think you need to figure this out yourself, does not seem to be the most easy piecy exercise :p, interesting one though!

Comment: Well thank you for your help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem of this nature is best derived from first principles and a tree-based analysis. The figure below shows the event space as a tree. The leaves correspond to the events $\{X=k\}$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots, n+1$. Each node in the graph represents an **event**, and the product of the conditional probabilities on the path from the root to any node is the probability of that event.

[image: Event Space Tree]

Using this analysis, it is now easy to derive a closed form for $P(X=K)$. Look at the pattern:

$$P(X=1) = \frac{m}{n+m}$$

$$P(X=2) = \frac{n}{n+m}\frac{m}{n+m-1}$$

$$P(X=2) = \frac{n}{n+m}\frac{n-1}{n+m-1}\frac{m}{n+m-2}$$

$$P(X=k) = \left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-2}\frac{n-i}{n+m-i}\right) \frac{m}{n+m-(k-1)}$$

This notation is suggestive of the idea that for the first white ball to arrive at draw $k$, we need to draw $k-1$ red balls in succession.

Now let us analyze the expectation $E(X)$. We will number the red balls $R_1, \dots, R_n$. Let the indicator random variable $I_j$ = 1 if ball $R_j$ was chosen before the first white ball, 0 otherwise. What is the probability $P(I_j = 1)$? This is simply $\frac{1}{m+1} (can you see why?).

It follows that

$$X = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n}I_j$$

$$E(X) = E(1+\sum_{j=1}^{n}I_j) $$

$$E(X) = 1 + E(\sum_{j=1}^{n}I_j)) $$

$$E(X) = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n}E(I_j)) $$

$$E(X) = 1 + \frac{n}{m+1}$$

Hopefully this should be enough for you to complete the rest of the questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot!